# MINI Cooper 2014, 5 door Hatch, one side DRL/Parking light sometimes on, sometimes fail to turn on

Tags: mini-cooper, daytime-running-lights, hatch

It's a MINI Cooper 2014, 5 door hatchback.

I have my front bumper replaced after an accident. And after I got my car back, I noticed that, sometimes, **not every time**, the front right side Daytime Running Light won't turn on and it gives the DRL failure warning on the dashboard.

I would say 1 in every 3 or 5 times when I turn the car on, it will have this issue.

What do you think is the reason causing this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Check from improperly connected connectors, broken or stripped wires, lamp bulb loose in its socket.

Comment: As well as a bad bulb in the form of a broken filament (which will sometimes come back in contact with its other half).

Comment: It happened again today and i gave it an old fashioned Kick and it turned on right away :D . Well still not 100% sure if that's wiring or loose bulb though.